# How do I manipulate this JSON data to update quantity of every attribute as 0?

Tags: php, html, json

For background info, in my website, I have a user login system along with data attributed to that user:

[image: PHPMyAdmin]

And the website looks like so:

[image: Website]

Now, the above screenshot is a just some of the products, with all the products in the JSON data linked to users.

The code I have written in order to update the JSON data upon clicking + or - is here:

```
<!-- script to adjust the quantity -->
    <script>
      function updateCounter(increment, e) {
        let section = e.target.dataset.section;
        let day = e.target.dataset.day;
        let product = e.target.dataset.product;
        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: '/getCounters.php',
          data: {},
          datatype: 'json',
        }).done((res) => {
          if(res != 'failed'){
            if(typeof(res) == 'string'){
              res = JSON.parse(res);
            }
            res = res.data[0];
            if(typeof(res) == 'string')
              res = JSON.parse(res);
            if (increment) 
                res[day][section][product] = parseInt(res[day][section][product]) + 1;
            else 
                res[day][section][product] = parseInt(res[day][section][product]) - 1;
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: '/updateCounters.php',
              data: res,
              datatype: 'json',
            }).done((res2) => {
              console.log(res2)
              if(res2 == 'successfull'){
                if (increment) e.target.previousSibling.previousSibling.textContent = res[day][section][product];
                else e.target.nextSibling.nextSibling.textContent = res[day][section][product];
              }else{
                window.location.href = '/login.php'
              }
              
            });
          }else{
            window.location.href = '/login.php'
          }

        })
      }
      $(document).ready(() => {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: '/getCounters.php',
          data: {},
          datatype: 'json',
        }).done((res) => {
          if(res != 'failed'){
            if(typeof(res) == 'string'){
              res = JSON.parse(res);
            }
            res = res.data[0];
            if(typeof(res) == 'string')
              res = JSON.parse(res);
            Object.entries(res).forEach(([key, value]) => {
              Object.entries(value).forEach(([keyInner, valueInner]) => {
                Object.entries(valueInner).forEach(([keyInner2, valueInner2]) => {
                  $(`*[data-section='${keyInner}'][data-day='${key}'][data-product='${keyInner2}']`)[0].nextSibling.nextSibling.textContent = valueInner2;
                })
              })
            });
          }else{
            window.location.href = '/login.php'
          }
        });
      })

      document.onclick = e => {
          if (e.target.className.startsWith('btn') && e.target.dataset.quantity) {
            if (e.target.dataset.quantity === 'minus') {
              //Can't go below zero
              if (parseInt(e.target.nextSibling.nextSibling.textContent) > 0) {
                updateCounter(false, e);
              }
            } else if (e.target.dataset.quantity === 'plus') {
              updateCounter(true, e);
            }
          }
        }
```

And here is my **updateCounters.php** class:

```
session_start();
include 'conn.php';
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
if($_POST){
    if($email && $email !== ''){
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $email);
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET data = '" . json_encode($_POST) . "' WHERE email='$email'";
    
        if ($conn->query($sql) === true) {      
            echo 'successfull';
        }else{
            echo 'failed';
        }
        $conn->close();
    }else{
        echo 'failed';
    }
}
```

As well as my **getCounters.php** class:

```
session_start();
include 'conn.php';
$email = isset($_SESSION['email'])? $_SESSION['email'] : '';
if($email && $email !== ''){
    // die(var_dump($_SESSION));
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $email);
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT data FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $num_row = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    if ($num_row > 0) {     
        $data['error'] = false;
        $data['data'] = $row;
        echo json_encode($data);
    }else{
        $data['error'] = true;
        $data['data'] = $row;
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
    $conn->close();
}else{
    echo 'failed';
}
```

**Everything above works. Below is what I need help with.**

Now, notice in my website screenshot I have a reset button. That button should call resetCounters(), which should change/reset all data to 0. Ideally I want a warning prompt to confirm if the user does want to after clicking reset.

The reset button should change all the data values as 0 if they are not already.

**Here is my attempt at this reset function, which does not seem to work. I don't know why. Any help is appreciated:**

```
function resetCounters(){
          $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/getCounters.php',
            data: {},
            datatype: 'json',
          }).done((res) => {
            if(res != 'failed'){
              if(typeof(res) == 'string'){
                res = JSON.parse(res);
              }
              res = res.data[0];
              if(typeof(res) == 'string')
                res = JSON.parse(res);
              Object.entries(res).forEach(([key, value]) => {
                Object.entries(value).forEach(([keyInner, valueInner]) => {
                  Object.entries(valueInner).forEach(([keyInner2, valueInner2]) => {
                    $(`*[data-section='${keyInner}'][data-day='${key}'][data-product='${keyInner2}']`)[0].nextSibling.nextSibling.textContent = 0;
                  })
                })
              });
              $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/updateCounters.php',
                data: res,
                datatype: 'json',
              }).done((res2) => {
                console.log(res2)
                if(res2 == 'successfull'){
                  window.location.href = '/index.php'
                }else{
                  window.location.href = '/login.php'
                }
                
              });
            }else{
              window.location.href = '/login.php'
            }
          })
        }
```

Just incase, here is my HTML line to call this function with this button:

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-danger"onclick="resetCounters()">Reset</button>
```

**As requested more information, here is the portion of HTML code for the page for demo and sale of "OfficeJet Pro":**

```
 <div id="Thursday">
          <!-- break from shift selector and time in shift selector -->
          <br>
          <p style="text-align: center">2:00 - 6:00PM | 240 Minutes<br><em>Tip: tap the title of product to view Best Buy stock!</em></p>
          
          <button class="btn btn-outline-danger" onclick="text(Thursday)">Reset</button>

          <h3 style="padding-top: 4%; padding-bottom: 2%; text-align: center;">Printers Section</h3>

          <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups" style="text-align: right; margin-bottom: 7px;">
            <div class="btn-group me-2" role="group" aria-label="First group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="window.location.href='https://www.bestbuy.ca/en-ca/search?path=soldandshippedby0enrchstring%253ABest%2BBuy&search=officejet+pro';" target="_blank">Demo - OfficeJet Pro</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-quantity="minus" data-day='thursday' data-product='demo_officeJetPro' data-section='printers'>-</button>
              <button-disabled type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">0</button-disabled>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-quantity="plus" data-day='thursday' data-product='demo_officeJetPro' data-section='printers'>+</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class=" btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups" style="text-align: center; margin-bottom: 23px;">
            <div class="btn-group me-2" role="group" aria-label="First group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="window.location.href='https://www.bestbuy.ca/en-ca/search?path=soldandshippedby0enrchstring%253ABest%2BBuy&search=officejet+pro';">Sale - OfficeJet Pro</button-disabled>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-quantity="minus" data-day='thursday' data-product='sale_officeJetPro' data-section='printers'>-</button>
                <button-disabled type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">0</button-disabled>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-quantity="plus" data-day='thursday' data-product='sale_officeJetPro' data-section='printers'>+</button>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: `$email && $email !== ''` is the same as `$email`.  Use prepared statements instead of `mysqli_real_escape_string`.  I don't think zero rows should be reported as an "error".  You are going to give me nightmares with `json_encode($_POST)` in your sql.

Comment: Are you double encoding `data` when you `get` it from the db? Once when you store it and once again when you pass it to js?

Comment: @mickmackusa Yeah.  My first time writing complex SQL/PHP code. I have no idea what i'm doing to be frank.

Comment: Can't you just use a JQuery selector to target all item values in the DOM and set their value to 0, then trigger the `update` process to send the batch of zeros to the server-side?

Comment: @mickmackusa What do you mean? I mean, would that mean I have to restart everything in terms of my current code?

Comment: I don't know what HTML markup looks like beneath Printers Section, so I cannot suggest a jquery selector.  You don't need to scrap all current code.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thanks mickmack. I have updated the post with HTML code at the bottom of the question. The 0 in this HTML is like a placeholder.

Comment: @mickmackusa is there way that I can perhaps put a JSON file with that data (first screenshot in this question) with all 0's as the data values, then have the reset button somehow post that json file and replace it for that user in the database in the column "data" in PHPMyAdmin panel?

Comment: On second thought, I believe I recommend a complete rewrite.  I wouldn't make a trip to the database to gather the stored payload every time a plus or minus was clicked, then modify the one value, then upload the single change.  I wouldn't store the data as a json string BECAUSE you intend to individually modify aspects of the payload.  Please read about Database Normalization.  If the user wants to to change 0 to 3, then your script will be making 6 round trips to the db -- this is not good and due to lag, you might get buggy behaviors. Try allowing a single submission when the user is done.

Comment: MySQL supports JSON data types.  If you use them, you won't have to fetch anything in this way.  You can just run the query to manipulate the data, which is what you should do.  The database should be your atomic source of truth.  If you fetch data, do something do it, then write it again, the data might have changed in the database in between those times by another user on the system at the same time.